# not able to show tinymce on partial, dynamically added textarea in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce

Not able to show tinymce on a partial, dynamically added textarea in Ruby on Rails app

So I have a reports views which has `new.html.erb`at bottom for tinymce I added tag `<%= tinymce %>` which works and shows tinymce editor for my `description` and `table_of_content` textarea

But I have `Add Faq` button, clicking on which renders a question and answer partial which should have textarea for `answer` field

```
   <%= f.text_area :question %>
   <%= f.text_area :answer, class: "tinymce", :rows=>"15"  %>  
   <%= f.link_to_remove "Remove", :class => 'btn btn-xs btn-primary'%>
```

The tinymce editor is not visible for this partial. I tried adding tinymce tag in partial page, but because of that tinymce editor will not show for description and table_of_content textarea

Comment: Did you try to initialize manually? like this https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails#manual-initialization

Comment: @Vishal Tried this it is not working for me